# Can I use Pandas groub by while dropping first and last entries in each group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that represents the trips I have taken for work. Each row is a single trip, with a column for the date and the number of kilometers traveled.

I get reimbursed on a per kilometer basis for every trip besides the first and the last of each day (these are considered ordinary travel to and from work).

So my data frame looks something like this:

```
day, distance
1, 5
1, 2
1, 7
2, 11
2, 11
3, 4
3, 10
3, 5
3, 12
```

I would like to add a column in here that flags all but the first and last trips of the day. Such as:

```
day, distance, claimable
1, 5, 0
1, 2, 1
1, 7, 0
2, 11, 0
2, 11, 0
3, 4, 0
3, 10, 1
3, 5, 1
3, 12, 0
```

Assuming I have a dataframe with the columns above is there a way to do something like this:

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'day':(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                   'dist':(5,2,7,11,11,4,10,5,12),
                  },)
df['claim'] = 0

# set the value of the "claimable" column to 1 on all 
# but the first and last trip of the day

df.groupby("day").nth(slice(1,-1)).loc[:, "claim"] = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day':(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
    'dist':(5,2,7,11,11,4,10,5,12),
})

def is_claimable(group):
    claim = np.ones(len(group), dtype='int8')
    claim[[0, -1]] = 0
    return claim

df['claim'] = df.groupby("day")['dist'].transform(is_claimable)
```

Output:

```
>>> df

   day  dist  claim
0    1     5      0
1    1     2      1
2    1     7      0
3    2    11      0
4    2    11      0
5    3     4      0
6    3    10      1
7    3     5      1
8    3    12      0
```

Comment: it could be slow because you are using more complex function tu transform

Comment: This is fine, I am working on a month by month basis, and dont travel *that* much each day. So the dataframe has less than 100 rows. But this works nicely! Thanks

Comment: @ansev That is only noticeable for quite large datasets. Anyway, your solution is not readable and involves a bunch of operations (although vectorized), so doubt it's faster

Comment: @AndrewMicallef No problem, glad to help! Yeah, with 100 rows you can't really notice.  The time difference should be in the order of microseconds or lower.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `transform` and take the `first` and `last` position

```
g  = df.reset_index().groupby('day')['index']
con = (df.index == g.transform('first')) | (df.index == g.transform('last'))
df['new'] = (~con).astype(int)
df
Out[117]: 
   day  dist  new
0    1     5    0
1    1     2    1
2    1     7    0
3    2    11    0
4    2    11    0
5    3     4    0
6    3    10    1
7    3     5    1
8    3    12    0
```

Answer (score 3):

if you sort your dataframe by day column:

```
df['claim'] = (df['day'].eq(df['day'].shift()) & 
               df['day'].eq(df['day'].shift(-1))).astype(int)
```

Diff version @ Rodalm

```
(df['day'].diff().eq(0) & df['day'].diff(-1).eq(0)).astype(int)
```

Or use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then compare with 0 and next

```
c = df.groupby('day').cumcount()
df['claim'] = (c.ne(0) & c.lt(c.shift(-1))).astype(int)
#df['claim'] = (c.gt(c.shift()) & c.lt(c.shift(-1))).astype(int)
print(df)
   day  dist  claim
0    1     5      0
1    1     2      1
2    1     7      0
3    2    11      0
4    2    11      0
5    3     4      0
6    3    10      1
7    3     5      1
8    3    12      0
```

Comment: @Andrew Micallef please check update without groupby

Comment: @BENY I also like yours:) +1,  I found a version without groupby

Comment: I can see that this works, and have no real objection to it, I just chose readability. I prefer Rodlams answer because it is plainly clear what is going on. And if I ever get audited then I would like to have code I can understand to fall back on.

Comment: I like your new solution! You can even make it cleaner using `diff` instead of `shift`. `df['claim'] = (df['day'].diff().eq(0) & df['day'].diff(-1).eq(0)).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pivot and use `first_valid_index` and `last_valid_index`; of course this will fail if there are duplicates in the combination of index and columns:

```py
positions = df.pivot(None, 'day', 'distance')
first = positions.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)
last = positions.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)
positions = np.concatenate([first.ravel(), last.ravel()])
df.assign(claimable = np.where(df.index.isin(positions), 0, 1))

   day  distance  claimable
0    1         5          0
1    1         2          1
2    1         7          0
3    2        11          0
4    2        11          0
5    3         4          0
6    3        10          1
7    3         5          1
8    3        12          0
```

Using `transform`, as in the other answers, does not have to worry about duplicates.